# Variable not initialized with a constant expression

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a novice programmer who is learning C++.

Below are the relevant parts of my code. VSCode throws an error *'size' not initialized with a constant expression*, and I'm unclear about the underlying error(s) in which I'm making.

```
  int min, max;
  min = max = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
    if(a[i]/int(pow(10,exp))%10>max) max = a[i];
    if(a[i]/int(pow(10,exp))%10<min) min = a[i];
  }
  return std::array<int,2> {min,max};
}

std::vector<int> radixSort(std::vector<int> a){
  int xp,maxval;
  xp = maxval = 0;
  int xpv = pow(10, xp);
  for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
    if(a[i]>maxval) maxval = a[i];
  }
  while(maxval/pow(10/xp) != 0){
    std::array<int, 2> rg = findRange(a,xp);
    int min = rg[0];
    int size = rg[1]-rg[0]+1; //error at rg[1]: attempt to access storage one position past the end of an array of 1 elements
    std::array<int,size> count;// Variable size cannot be used as constant
    ...
```

I'd like to clarify a few details:

1. I've returned an array size 2 with 2 elements {max,min} from my function findRange. So why is it that the compiler only interprets it as one? Changing the function return type to std::vector doesn't seem to fix the problem.
2. I realized that array sizes need to be fixed at compile time, but when I put *const* or *constexpr* infront of a *size* variable it doesn't fix the problem.

Feel free to point out any other mistakes in my code. Thanks!

EDIT: Changed int i to int i=0 in the first for loop

Comment: The value of `size` just can't be calculated at compile-time, so it's not possible to use for an array dimension. Consider `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Another option for some cases is to use constexpr vector from newer C++ standards, but that does not seem viable here, at the first glance at least

Comment: Your code uses a variable named `size`, with value computed at runtime, in a context where  a compile-time constant is expected..  Also `i` is uninitialised in the loop that computes `min` and `max`.   Accessing its value (or incrementing it, since incrementing a variable means accessing its value) gives undefined behaviour.    Your code seems to be assuming it is initialised to zero, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

it is just because of  array of size 2 with 2 elements try it with inheritance concept

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).